# Unexpected token issue in truffle on Windows

Tags: truffle, consensys-truffle, truffleruby

I am trying to install truffle on node version 8.9.0 and npm version 5.5.1. It got installed but am not able to do anything in that. every time I try any command, even try to unbox it shows an error.

```
C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.0\node_modules\truffle\build\86.bundled.js:55160
  } catch {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.f.require (C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.0\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:603:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

the required node version is Node v12 or later. https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/installation/#requirements